# PI Zero / Fault Segmentation / Disk and Power are good

Tags: pi-zero-w, pi-zero-w-2

I'm able to download the dotnet framework using this command:

```
curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --channel STS
```

as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment

I have experience with this on my PI4b, but on the PI Zero something is wrong - perhaps .net7? There are videos running .net running .net6, so I figured .Net7 was a sure thing.

That said when I run `dotnet --version` or `dotnet --info` I get an immediate segment fault.

To prove the power and disk are ok, I put the same disk into my PI4b, and the commands work, but fail on the PIZero.

Any ideas?

The only other difference is that on the PIZero .dotnet is installed as a hidden folder, but on the PI4b, its seems to NOT hidden (I'm not a UNIX/Ubuntu expert in any way, and this is my first real application on PI).

Here is the CPUInfo from the PI Zero:

```
cat //proc//cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : 9000c1
Serial          : 0000000066e67011
Model           : Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1
pizero@pizero:~/.dotnet $ dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.84+ (dom@buildbot) (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1613 Thu Jan 5 11:58:09 GMT 2023
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1
[    0.000000] random: crng init done
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x0bc00000, size 256 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001bffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001bffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001bffffff]
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 113680
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 video=Composite-1:720x480@60i smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:E6:70:11 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=550bfb3c-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 177172K/458752K available (9041K kernel code, 1335K rwdata, 2948K rodata, 436K init, 546K bss, 19436K reserved, 262144K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 31903 entries in 94 pages
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocated 94 pages with 5 groups
[    0.000000] trace event string verifier disabled
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000007] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 2147483647500ns
[    0.000102] clocksource: timer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275 ns
[    0.000216] bcm2835: system timer (irq = 27)
[    0.001145] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001795] printk: console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001901] Calibrating delay loop... 697.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=3489792)
[    0.060383] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.060647] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.061010] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.061100] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.063492] cgroup: Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.063998] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.066652] Setting up static identity map for 0x8220 - 0x8258
[    0.068277] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.082226] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
[    0.082697] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.082801] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes, linear)
[    0.125449] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.127871] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.132796] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.139308] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.140026] audit: type=2000 audit(0.130:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.141430] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.142477] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.142586] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.142924] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.156177] bcm2835-mbox 2000b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.191091] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2023-01-05T10:48:31, variant start
[    0.201126] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 8ba17717fbcedd4c3b6d4bce7e50c7af4155cba9
[    0.261688] Kprobes globally optimized
[    0.273493] bcm2835-dma 20007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.277043] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.277651] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.277826] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.277999] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.278589] usb_phy_generic phy: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.278989] usb_phy_generic phy: dummy supplies not allowed for exclusive requests
[    0.279577] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.279642] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.279741] PTP clock support registered
[    0.282848] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer
[    0.370752] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.370976] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.371285] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.371739] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.373014] simple-framebuffer 1eaa9000.framebuffer: framebuffer at 0x1eaa9000, 0x151800 bytes
[    0.373123] simple-framebuffer 1eaa9000.framebuffer: format=a8r8g8b8, mode=720x480x32, linelength=2880
[    2.254139] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 90x30
[    2.263249] simple-framebuffer 1eaa9000.framebuffer: fb0: simplefb registered!
[    2.288184] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    2.292204] IP idents hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    2.297734] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    2.305210] Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    2.309324] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    2.313512] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    2.317660] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    2.321917] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    2.326085] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    2.330694] NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
[    2.336344] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    2.340448] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    2.344459] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    2.348304] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    2.354217] armv6-pmu arm-pmu: hw perfevents: no irqs for PMU, sampling events not supported
[    2.362122] hw perfevents: enabled with armv6_1176 PMU driver, 3 counters available
[    2.415069] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    2.419874] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    2.437434] zbud: loaded
[    2.444807] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    2.450203] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    2.454545] Key type id_resolver registered
[    2.458428] Key type id_legacy registered
[    2.462416] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    2.466295] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    2.472268] Key type asymmetric registered
[    2.476262] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    2.480149] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 247)
[    2.483942] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    2.487568] io scheduler kyber registered
[    2.505944] bcm2835-rng 20104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    2.510409] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x1ec00000 mem_size:0x20000000(512 MiB)
[    2.519996] gpiomem-bcm2835 20200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x20200000
[    2.547891] brd: module loaded
[    2.565845] loop: module loaded
[    2.570956] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    2.578008] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    2.581868] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    3.314302] Core Release: 2.80a
[    3.317968] Setting default values for core params
[    3.321495] Finished setting default values for core params
[    3.525456] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    3.528964] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    3.532448] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    3.535985] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    3.539578] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode

[    3.544801] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1074: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = cbd04000 dma = 0x8bd04000 len=9024
[    3.555207] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    3.571907] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled

[    3.572183] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:457: FIQ on core 0

[    3.578581] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:458: FIQ ASM at c068ef38 length 36

[    3.584619] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:497: MPHI regs_base at dc810000
[    3.590863] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    3.594159] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    3.597488] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: irq 56, io mem 0x00000000
[    3.600679] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    3.603853] Init: Power Port (0)
[    3.607485] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    3.613871] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.617206] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    3.620498] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.84+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    3.623872] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 20980000.usb
[    3.628625] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.632088] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    3.636790] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    3.636830] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    3.636847] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    3.636877] Module dwc_common_port init
[    3.637540] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    3.641433] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    3.649027] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    3.652408] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    3.656819] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    3.662132] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    3.666463] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    3.670233] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.673731] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.685020] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    3.688942] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    3.692627] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    3.697120] registered taskstats version 1
[    3.700456] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    3.721873] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    3.725605] 20201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    3.736808] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    3.741111] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    3.747464] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    3.750931] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    3.784325] sdhost: log_buf @ 92f162a7 (8bd03000)
[    3.836687] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    3.864257] of_cfs_init
[    3.868345] of_cfs_init: OK
[    3.874788] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=550bfb3c-02...
[    3.917474] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    3.924677] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0007
[    3.929923] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD32G 29.3 GiB
[    3.939627]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    3.944969] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD32G 29.3 GiB
[    3.994661] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    4.001816] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    4.015886] devtmpfs: mounted
[    4.029622] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 436K
[    4.033458] Kernel memory protection not selected by kernel config.
[    4.038263] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    4.043118] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    4.046860]   with arguments:
[    4.046883]     /sbin/init
[    4.046899]   with environment:
[    4.046912]     HOME=/
[    4.046925]     TERM=linux
[    4.725640] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    5.069187] NET: Registered PF_INET6 protocol family
[    5.075711] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    5.079429] In-situ OAM (IOAM) with IPv6
[    5.217875] systemd[1]: systemd 247.3-7+rpi1+deb11u1 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified)
[    5.230762] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    5.262567] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <pizero>.
[    8.359041] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Multi-User System.
[    8.376822] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    8.389383] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[    8.401468] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    8.413178] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    8.423320] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    8.433623] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    8.445842] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    8.460729] systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[    8.472015] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[    8.482352] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    8.492359] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    8.509009] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    8.521057] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    8.531781] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    8.544799] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    8.556415] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    8.568448] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    8.593782] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    8.605449] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    8.616852] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Huge Pages File System being skipped.
[    8.635313] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    8.676568] systemd[1]: Mounting RPC Pipe File System...
[    8.734813] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    8.795601] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[    8.820661] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS being skipped.
[    8.861106] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    8.906181] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[    8.989932] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    9.106724] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module configfs...
[    9.203288] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    9.264995] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module fuse...
[    9.338681] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    9.431144] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    9.608744] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    9.760210] fuse: init (API version 7.34)
[    9.770975] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    9.924726] systemd[1]: Starting Coldplug All udev Devices...
[   10.178134] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   10.229003] systemd[1]: Mounted RPC Pipe File System.
[   10.309351] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[   10.419302] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[   10.505460] systemd[1]: Finished Restore / save the current clock.
[   10.614266] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[   10.733533] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Succeeded.
[   10.763284] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module configfs.
[   10.817890] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[   10.873211] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[   10.926383] systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Succeeded.
[   10.983657] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module fuse.
[   11.043333] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[   11.150130] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[   11.353786] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[   11.465432] systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
[   11.604656] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[   11.743343] systemd[1]: Finished File System Check on Root Device.
[   11.807517] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[   11.878158] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[   12.044220] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   12.215367] systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
[   12.248450] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   13.033595] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   13.566667] systemd-journald[103]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[   13.587507] systemd-journald[103]: File /var/log/journal/b727669b1534417b903aaf90c6b7d066/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   18.272738] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   18.389158] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[   18.389223] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[   18.423632] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[   18.453129] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   19.732699] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   19.742737] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   19.888208] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: there is not valid maps for state default
[   20.786944] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   20.799778] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   20.811743] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   21.090457] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   21.146832] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   21.426946] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[   21.428191] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[   21.448006] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[   21.450621] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[   21.450703] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[   21.450753] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[   21.450792] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[   21.450829] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[   21.551708] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video20
[   21.583101] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video21
[   21.624016] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video22
[   21.649640] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video23
[   21.649721] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[   21.649771] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[   21.649810] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[   21.649846] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[   21.650359] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[   21.973177] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   22.063752] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[   22.090301] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[   22.177225] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[   22.177341] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[   22.206047] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[   22.206150] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[   22.237656] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video18
[   22.237763] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 image_fx
[   22.256731] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video31
[   22.256838] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode_image
[   28.192076] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[   28.454392] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   31.498696] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   31.625468] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   32.117873] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   32.129516] cfg80211: loaded regulatory.db is malformed or signature is missing/invalid
[   33.579566] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   33.579763] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   33.579783] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   33.579820] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   33.579843] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   33.579888] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   33.627587] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   33.627632] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   33.627776] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   33.628113] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   33.813319] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x1541a9a6
[   33.949721] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   33.956788] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   34.219249] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   34.230948] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Jul 19 2021 03:24:18 version 7.45.98 (TOB) (56df937 CY) FWID 01-8e14b897
[   34.403001] cam-dummy-reg: disabling
[   34.595312] checking generic (1eaa9000 151800) vs hw (0 ffffffff)
[   34.595354] fb0: switching to vc4 from simple
[   34.615884] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x30
[   34.628875] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[   34.670268] Registered IR keymap rc-cec
[   34.670574] rc rc0: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/20902000.hdmi/rc/rc0
[   34.670886] input: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/20902000.hdmi/rc/rc0/input0
[   34.753030] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20902000.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
[   34.753971] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20004000.txp (ops vc4_txp_ops [vc4])
[   34.754727] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   34.755520] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   34.756269] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20807000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   34.756885] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20c00000.v3d (ops vc4_v3d_ops [vc4])
[   34.856482] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for soc:gpu on minor 0
[   34.865114] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[   36.517396] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   36.517439] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   36.517473] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   36.661385] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[   38.104271] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[   39.431773] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   41.446240] ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time_ms instead
[   45.284981] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] Cannot find a
```

Comment: *"I get an immediate segment fault"* -> These are not caused by power issues, they are generally coding or compilation bugs.  The other information in your question is also not relevant.  What might be is an exact cut n' paste of the error.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks but how do you explain it running correctly on the 4b - all i did was put the disk I was using in the zero, and put it in the 4b and it ran just fine.  Perhaps too much is running for the Pi Zero W (i'm looking for a Pi Zero 2w to see if it will run - if anyone knows where there is stock?)

Comment: search for "`raspberry pi zero .NET`" and you'll find that .NET is NOT supported on a raspberry pi zero

Comment: @JaromandaX seeing is believing - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TS4DNGByIoc

Comment: Sure, that's a Raspbery pi zero **2** - didn't think you had one of those

Comment: *"how do you explain"* -> A recurrent segmentation fault is not caused by lack of power but by a software deficiency, and such deficiencies may show up on one platform but not on another (which is how they may be largely unnoticed).  For example, you can work on something for months on a 64-bit machine, then find when it is first ported to 32-bit that there are errors that did not previously cause a problem (but they are still errors).

Comment: @Jaromanda I'm sorry your right! Bought zero 2w, but checked the back and it's NOT! The hours I spent on this.  Thanks so much for your comment. Leave it as a answer and I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dotnet` officially doesn't support ARMv6 architecture. But from Net7, it can be compiled to ARMv6, but only community supported.

see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74561337/can-i-publish-targeting-linux-armv6-runtime-in-net-core-7

Comment: As this I my first project on Raspberry PI, I didn't realize there was a significant difference between PI Zero 2 and PI Zero 2W.   Turns out that I was shipped a PI Zero 2, and hence the resulting confusion.  Thanks for your input.